# Lit-element with Object-type properties

Tags: polymer, lit-element

How to use Lit-element with Object-type property?
I think defining myelement works:

```
static get properties() {
    return {
        whales:Object
    }
}
constructor() {
    super();
    this.whales={"nb":0};
}
```

html, this works also:

```
       <my-element id="mytest" whales='{"nb":2}'></my-element>
```

But I can't get setAttribute to work:

```
myElement.setAttribute("whales", {"nb":4});
```

EDIT:
Thank you mishu, your answer helped me to solve my problem. Here is full working example, if someone wants to know. However there is still one thing I couldn't get working: I don't know how to give a property initial value declaratively, if the value is an object (object is handled as a string).

index.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Lit-html test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="module" src="./components/my-e.js"></script>

  <button id="reset" onclick="reset()">reset</button>
  <p>1 works: <my-e id="mytest"></my-e></p>
  <p>2 doesn't work: <my-e id="mytest2" person='{"name":"Joe", "age":32}'></my-e></p>
  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
     function updatePerson(e) {
  var myE = e.target;
  myE.person = e.detail;
  myE._requestRender();
}
function reset() {
  var p = { "name": "Jack", "age": 20 };
  var myE = document.getElementById('mytest');
  myE.person = p;
  myE._requestRender();

  myE = document.getElementById('mytest2');
  myE.person = p;
  myE._requestRender();
}
document.getElementById('mytest').addEventListener('person', updatePerson);
document.getElementById('mytest2').addEventListener('person', updatePerson);
```

my-e.js:

```
import { LitElement, html } from './lit-element.js';
class MyE extends LitElement {
  static get properties() {
    return {
      person: Object
    }
  }
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.person = { "name": "Paul", "age": 40 };
    this.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
      await this.renderComplete;
      var p = {};
      p.name = this.person.name + ", a";
      p.age = this.person.age + 1;
      this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('person', { detail: p }))
    });
  }
  _render({ person }) {
    return html`
         <p> Name: ${person.name}</p>
         <p>Age: ${person.age}</p>
    `;
  }
}
customElements.define('my-e', MyE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There you are trying to update a property, not really to set an attribute, and you don't have `reflectToAttribute` on the property. But you can try to use simply:

```
myElement.whales = {nb: 4};
```

**UPDATE**: I see that you changed the "scope" of the question.. so, you should be able to pass an object declaratively as long as the JSON is correct. You can see it in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1jLepepq/605/).

Comment: Thank you, I got the code working. I have edited my question to include the working code. I still have one question about object property, please see my question.

Comment: @grohjy I updated the answer with a demo showing the value received from "outside" as JSON..

Comment: I think my example has correct JSON (single and double quotations in right places). So I believe there is some bug in lit-element, because json-statement is handled as string not as object. Thank you for your help @mishu

Answer (score 1):

`<my-e id="mytest2" person='{"name":"Joe", "age":32}'></my-e>`

Should have been 
`<my-e id="mytest2" person='${{"name":"Joe", "age":32}}'></my-e>`
If you are using lit-extended. But this notation is going to be removed and is currently deprecated.

Hence the better option would be to write it as:
`<my-e id="mytest2" .person={"name":"Joe", "age":32}></my-e>`

You can find the details at this [documentation](https://github.com/Polymer/lit-html/blob/4c627e7a14478243e8d7c797a53e96e3984e586d/src/lit-html.ts#L31-L58)

Answer (score 0):

This example is tested in **Lit 2.3.1**. It should also work with lit-element.

**Note:** `While passing object type attribute through html outer quotes must be single quotes and inner quotes must be double quotes.( like this: article='{"title": "Hello"}' ).`

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Lit 2.3.1</title>
</head>
<body>
  <my-page article='{"title": "Hello", "text": "World", "lines": 120}'></my-page>
</body>
</html>
```

**my-page.js**

```
import {LitElement, html} from 'lit';

class MyPage extends LitElement {
  static properties = {
    article: {
      type: Object, 
      attribute: 'article'
    }
  };

  render() {
    return html`
      <div>
        <p>${this.article.title}</p>
        <p>${this.article.text}</p>
        <p>${this.article.lines}</p>
      </div>`;
  }
}

customElements.define('my-page', MyPage);
```